# SQL Server Managment Studio Connect Dialog Authorization Dropdown empty

Tags: ssms

When I run SSMS and connect to server, the Authentication dropdown never populates, so I can't select a type of authentication!  I've rebooted and reinstalled v18.6 but it still does this.  Even entering the server name doesn't change things.  Clicking on Options>> just expands the dialog but the dialog is blank. How do I fix this so that it shows authentication options again?

[image: SSMS Connect to Server Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  If you go into C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\ and remove the "SQL Server Management Studio" directory and run SSMS, it starts correctly.  Apparently some corrupt settings.  I believe your settings could be in AppData\Local or AppData\LocalLow depending on your configuration.